# Can $b+c$ in the pythagorean triplets $(a, b, c)$ be a prime number?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, can $b + c$ be a prime number?

Comment: If $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is primitive, then $b+c=(2x-1)^2,x\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Pythagorean Triple $(a, b, c)$ is not primitive, then $b+c$ is trivially composite.  Thus, let it be primitive.  Then $$a=m^2-n^2$$ $$b=2mn$$ $$c=m^2+n^2$$ where $b$ and $a$ are interchangeable.  Then we are looking at the sum $b+c=2m^2$ or $(m+n)^2$

---

Looking back at this answer, the only possibility for $b+c$ to be prime is when $m=1, b=1-n^2$, and thus $b+c=2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: No problem.  If my answer was helpful, you should check the checkmark under the arrows for my comment.  It gives me more reputation

Comment: @almagest Actually it wasn't correct.  I just corrected it.  Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a^2+b^2=c^2\implies b^2-c^2=-a^2\implies (b+c)(b-c)=-a^2 \implies b+c=\frac{a^2}{c-b}$ $ \implies b+c=a^2 \times \frac{1}{c-b}$

Comment: A lemma that will solve the problem when coupled with the hint: if $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $a^2$, then $p$, being a divisor of $a$, is less than or equal to $a$.